# 3 Tables into dropdown list

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, subtraction

I have 3 tables, Clients, Products, Transactions.
When we enter a product, it is given a PID (product id) and a CID (client ID), which relate to the Clients and Transaction tables. The transaction table has a CID and Quantity.

I am trying to list all unique products and quantities, some clients have 2 listings of the same product, so if 1 is 10 units and the other is 20, then that client has 30 of product a.

The transactions table lists all sales, which are subtracted from the total.
I need the query to show the product name, client name, quantity available.
Here is the code I have so far, apologies for the mess and thanks much for any help.

This is an Access database.

```
SELECT Min(Products.PID) exPID, 
       Min(Products.[Product Name]) AS exProdName,
       Min(Products.[Seller Asking]) AS exAsking, 
       Min(Products.CID) AS exClientID, 
       Min(Transactions.[CID Seller]) AS exSellerID,     
       Sum(Products.Quantity - ((SELECT Transactions.[No Units], Clients.Name, 
                                        Transactions.[CID Seller], Products.CID 
                                 FROM Transactions, Clients, Products 
                                 WHERE Transactions[CID Seller]=Products.CID)
           ) AS exSumofTrans),     
       Min(Clients.Name) AS exClientName, 
       Min(Transactions.[CID Seller]) AS exSeller
FROM Transactions, Clients, Products
WHERE (((Transactions.[CID Seller])=[Products].[CID] 
  AND   (Products.[PID])=([Transactions].[PID])));
```

First issue here is an error on the inner select.

The error says:

> 'Syntax error in query expression (Sum(Products.Quantity-((Select Transactions.[No Units], Clients.Name, Transactions.[CID Seller], Products.CID 
>   FROM Transactions, Clients, Products 
>   Where Transactions[CID Seller]=Products.CID)) as exSumofTrans)'.

Comment: The syntax error is here: `Transactions[CID Seller]` is missing the period between `Transactions` and `[CID Seller]`.

Comment: You can't use a SELECT statement inside another SELECT statement like that. Even if you could, your select statement returns 4 fields, how is Access supposed to substract that from Quantity? Also the parenthesis for Sum should close before the alias declaration. Finally you are using aggregate functions like Sum and Min but there is no GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some guessing based on what it looks like you are trying to do and I have no way of testing it so it may need further tweaking but this will get you on the right path:

```
SELECT Products.PID AS exPID,
    FIRST(Products.[Product Name]) AS exProdName,
    FIRST(Products.[Seller Asking]) AS exAsking,
    FIRST(Products.CID) AS exClientID,
    SUM(Products.Quantity)-FIRST(T.exNoUnits) AS exSumofTrans,
    T.exSellerID,
    FIRST(Clients.Name) AS exClientName
FROM (Products  
    INNER JOIN (SELECT [CID Seller] AS exSellerID, PID, SUM([No Units]) AS exNoUnits
        FROM Transactions GROUP BY [CID Seller], PID) AS T
        ON T.PID=Products.PID)
    INNER JOIN Clients ON T.exSellerID=Clients.CID
GROUP BY Products.PID, T.exSellerID
```

Comment: I am now getting duplicates of records from transactions table. I only need the row from products table if there is no transactions with that product id (PID).                                                                                                         SELECT Products.PID, Products.[Product Name], Products.Quantity, IIf([Product Balance].[PID]=[Products].[PID],[Product Balance].[Balance],[Products].[Quantity]) AS NewBal
FROM (Products LEFT JOIN [Product Balance] ON Products.PID = [Product Balance].PID) INNER JOIN [Product Types] ON Products.[Product Name] = [Product Types].PTID;